# invoke gridview paging using button outside the gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can you invoke the paging of a gridview using button from the outside of the gridview?

I have searched it but unfortunately I can't find the right logic for it. I'm  not talking about  creating a button for preview and next function inside the pager template of the gridview, but outside, the gridview itself like a remote button. Whenever I click either the preview or next button, the gridview will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the Button outside the Grid View. You can do grid view paging as follows on the button click.

Basically we need to set the pageindex of the grid view and rebind the data. You need to have the data stored in session/cache or get it afresh for the gridview.

```
protected void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ++gridview.PageIndex;  

 // if we have reached the last page, either set to first page. 
 // you could also do nothing.
 if (gridview.PageIndex >= gridview.PageCount)
 {
  gridview.PageIndex = 0;
 }

 gridview.DataSource = GetGridViewData(); // the data needs to be available.

 gridview.DataBind(); 
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark as answer for all to benefit as well.